# How can a field have a finite characteristic $p$, given that a field has no zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, positive-characteristic

The characteristic of a field is defined to be the smallest positive integer $p$ such that $$p \cdot 1 = 0.$$

But I have learned that field has no zero divisors. How is this possible?

Comment: A zero divisor is an element of the field. When you define the characteristic via that equation you consider $1$ an element of the field, whereas $p$ is an integer and the $\cdot$ is not the field operation: it stands for 'multiple' i.e. $p\cdot1$ means $1+1+...+1$ ($p$ times).

Answer (score 24):

The notation $p \cdot 1$ just means $1+1+\cdots+1$ ($p$ times), where $1$ is the unit of the field and $+$ is the addition in the field.

You can also interpret $p$ as this same element in the field, but in this case you'll have $p=0$.

Answer (score 21):

For any unital ring $R$, fields included, and for any $n \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$, we denote $$n \cdot 1 := \underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_n.$$ Now, $n \mapsto n \cdot 1$ is by construction a group homomorphism $$\phi: (\mathbb{Z}, +) \to (R, +) ,$$ (to achieve this we need to declare for $-m < 0$ that $(-m) \cdot 1 = -(m \cdot 1)$) and we define the **characteristic** of $R$ to be the additive order $c$ of the multiplicative unit $\phi(1) = 1_R$ of $R$, or more informally, "$c = 0$ in $R$". (If $n \cdot 1 \neq 0$ for all positive integers $n$, we usually say by convention that the field has characteristic $0$; some older sources say such fields have characteristic $\infty$ instead.)

**Example** Consider the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ with underlying set $\{0, 1\}$, with elements just an additive and multiplicative identity (respectively) and satisfying $1 + 1 := 0$. Since $0 \neq 1$, the characteristic of this field is $\operatorname{char} \mathbb{F}_2 = 2$.

**Remark** If the characteristic $c$ of a ring is positive and composite, say, $c = kl$ for $k, l > 1$, then $$\phi(k) \phi(l) = \phi(kl) = \phi(c) = 0 ,$$ so $\phi(k)$ and $\phi(l)$ (which are nonzero, because $k, l$ are both smaller than $c$) are zero divisors. In particular, the characteristic of any field must be $0$ or prime.

Answer (score 11):

If $R$ is a ring with identity, let's denote it by $1$. Let's also denote integers with boldface type. So $\mathbf{1}$ is the *integer* number one, for instance, $\mathbf{0}$ is the integer zero, whereas $0$ and $1$ are the neutral elements in $R$.

Since $R$ under addition is an abelian group, we can as usual define
$$\def\z#1{\mathbf{#1}}
\z{0}r=0,\qquad
(\z{n}+\z{1})r=\z{n}r+r
$$
that defines $\z{n}r$ for $\z{n}\ge\z{0}$. If $\z{n}<\z{0}$, define as usual
$$
\z{n}r=(-\z{n})(-r)
$$
It's easy to prove that, if $\varepsilon_R\colon\mathbb{Z}\to R$ is the map
$$
\varepsilon_R(\z{n})=\z{n}1
$$
(according to the definition above), then

1. $\varepsilon_R(\z{m}+\z{n})=\varepsilon_R(\z{m})+\varepsilon_R(\z{n})$
2. $\varepsilon_R(\z{m}\z{n})=\varepsilon_R(\z{m})\varepsilon_R(\z{n})$
3. $\varepsilon_R(\z{1})=1$

so $\varepsilon_R$ is a homomorphism of unital rings. Actually it is the *unique* unital ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group under addition and we're required that a homomorphism maps $\z{1}$ into $1$.

Like all ring homomorphisms, $\varepsilon_R$ has a kernel which is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, so we have $\ker\varepsilon_R=\z{k}\mathbb{Z}$ for a unique $\z{k}\ge\z{0}$.

If $\z{k}=\z{0}$, then $\varepsilon_R$ is injective. Otherwise, we have
$$
\z{k}1=0
$$
by definition of kernel, which means that
$$
\z{k}r=\underbrace{r+r+\dots+r}_{\z{k}}=(\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{\z{k}})r=
(\z{k}1)r=0r=0
$$
for every $r\in R$.

This integer $\z{k}$ is the *characteristic* of $R$.

If $R$ is an integral domain and $\z{k}>\z{0}$, suppose we have $\z{k}=\z{a}\z{b}$, with $\z{1}\le\z{a}<\z{k}$. Then, by definition of the characteristic, we know $\z{a}1\ne0$, but
$$
0=\z{k}1=\varepsilon_R(\z{k})=\varepsilon_R(\z{a})\varepsilon_R(\z{b})
$$
and so, being $R$ an integral domain, we have $\varepsilon_R(\z{b})=0$ which implies $\z{k}\mid\z{b}$. Therefore $\z{b}=\z{k}$ and $\z{a}=1$. It follows that $\z{k}$ is prime.

Saying $\z{k}1=0$ in a field (which is an integral domain) is not a contradiction, because $\z{k}$ is not an element of the field.

---

Normally one doesn't denote integers with different type than elements of the rings, which could lead to confusion. Most of the times, one simply writes $n$ instead of $n1$ (when $n$ is an integer), so we can even find $p=0$ when the characteristic of a field is the prime $p$. This should be simply interpreted as $p1=0$. With some experience, the notational problems disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a field is always an integral domain.

But having finite characteristic $p$ doesn't contradict this statement, as, as borne out in the comments and the other answers, $px=0$ doesn't refer to a product of nonzero field elements, but rather to repeated addition of the field element $x$ with itself.  Remember, a field is a ring, and a ring consists in an additive abelian group, hence a $\Bbb Z$- module, among other things.  Thus $px$ makes sense, and it being equal to zero is perfectly legal.